# Xcode shows all folders from the root folder

Tags: xcode14

I have a problem that the Xcode shows all projects from the root folder.

When I click NearRestaurant.xcodeproj, it runs as normal but when I click NearRestaurant.xcworkspace, it show all projects and I could not run my application.

I tried to close the Xcode and open it again but it does not show only the current project, and I see no way to fix it.
[image: This is what shows in Xcode]